# How to pass a specific data in a mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

i have a collection of the visits in a website, i need to do 3 graphs that show the visits. the first graph has to show a selected day divided per hour, the second a selected month divided per day and the third a selected year divided per month. i have the queries for all the 3 cases, but i did it with a casual date inserted directly in the query. i need to be able, for each case, to pass a selected day, month or a year from the graph. Than i have to implement these queries in my TS code.

i have datas (in the collection) like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab111a1646e371568c8cfa1"),
    "date" : ISODate("2018-03-20T13:46:30.018Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

now i show the 3 codes i have:

DAY

```
db.monitors.aggregate([  
  {"$match":{
    "date":{
        "$gte":ISODate("2018-03-22T00:00:00.000Z"), "$lt":ISODate("2018-03-23T00:00:00.000Z")}}
    },

  {"$group":{
    "_id":{
      "year":{"$year":"$date"},
      "month":{"$month":"$date"},
      "dayOfMonth":{"$dayOfMonth":"$date"},
      "hour":{"$hour":"$date"}
    },
    "count":{"$sum":1}
  }},

  {"$group":{
    "_id":{
      "year":"$_id.year",
        "month":"$_id.month",
      "dayOfMonth":"$_id.dayOfMonth"
    },
    "dailyCount":{"$sum":"$hourlyCount"},
    "hourlyData":{"$push":{"hour":"$_id.hour","count":"$count"}}
  }}
])
```

MONTH

```
db.monitors.aggregate([  
  {"$match":{
    "date":{
        "$gte":ISODate("2018-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"), "$lt":ISODate("2018-03-01T00:00:00.000Z")}}
    },

  {"$group":{
    "_id":{
      "year":{"$year":"$date"},
      "month":{"$month":"$date"},
      "dayOfMonth":{"$dayOfMonth":"$date"}
    },
    "count":{"$sum":1}
  }},

  {"$group":{
    "_id":{
      "year":"$_id.year",
        "month":"$_id.month",
      "dayOfMonth":"$_id.dayOfMonth"
    },
    "monthlyCount":{"$sum":"$dailyCount"},
    "dailyData":{"$push":{"dayOfMonth":"$_id.dayOfMonth","count":"$count"}}
  }}
])
```

YEAR

```
db.monitors.aggregate([  
  {"$match":{
    "date":{
        "$gte":ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"), "$lt":ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")}}
    },

  {"$group":{
    "_id":{
      "year":{"$year":"$date"},
      "month":{"$month":"$date"},
    },
    "count":{"$sum":1}
  }},

  {"$group":{
    "_id":{
      "year":"$_id.year",
        "month":"$_id.month",
    },
    "yearlyCount":{"$sum":"$monthlyCount"},
    "monthlyData":{"$push":{"month":"$_id.month","count":"$count"}}
  }}
])
```

Comment: Which data you wanted to pass in query?

Comment: In the graphs i want to implement the possibility to choose a specific date by, for example, a calendar. Or eventually for each graph to select only a day for the first, a month for the second and a year for the third.